# installing packages in docker containers

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am wondering how to install packages inside docker containers. My usecase is, that I have a jenkins server with few kinds of agents, including a docker agent template, that causes a docker container to be created and used for each build without a label by default, if no virtual machine environment is necessary. The problem is, how to, in a secure way if possible, install dependencies before a build in such a docker container? I don't think having many images each for a different project with separate needs is a nice idea, and modifying a single image each time some project needs a dependency will probably bloat that image in case I will need many of those. But normally, for security reasons, there is no root access inside of a container. How to cope with this situation/what are possible options?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins allows you to specify the docker image in which the agent will be created.

Example:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'maven:3-alpine'
        label 'my-defined-label'
        args  '-v /tmp:/tmp'
    }
}
```

In case you cannot find a public image on dockerhub that contains the necessary dependencies, you need to create a custom image. The way to do that is to create a Dockerfile and install the dependecies in it.

```
FROM base-image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...
```

You then either use this Dockerfile to build the agent, or build an image and put it on the jenkins host and use the pipeline syntax above to provision the agent.

You can use the Dockerfile directly:

```
agent { dockerfile { dir 'path-to-Dockerfile' } }
```

Comment: well, to be honest, I am not sure about security of those scripts. Someone who could write jenkinsfile's and commit them, could probably use the pipeline script to damage the master node, or one with running docker. Am I right? I am not using docker pipeline, but a cloud docker plugin where each build is by default run in it's own container without requesting that explicitly, but I only have one image unless I make multiple templates.

Comment: if I understand it correctly, but not sure if I do as I didn't currently learn pipelines, pipeline can be scripted, and those scripts are probably not so much restricted, so I could do, in theory, everything with the node the script fragment runs on, is that correct? So I can run docker containers, but I cannot fully use them as security boundaries. I would use pipelines for that purpose if whatever I said is wrong.